# 'WebHost' does not contain a definition for 'CreateDefaultBuilder'

Tags: api, asp.net-core

I work on the migration of an .NET CORE API.
Firstly, I have this error message :

> The name 'WebHost' does not exist in the current context

So Visual Studio suggest me to have this namespace :

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal;
```

I put it in my file, after that I have this error message :

> 'WebHost' does not contain a definition for 'CreateDefaultBuilder'

I don't know why it's doing that. Can I have some help ?

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args);
```

Comment: use Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting instead of "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal;"

Comment: On which version of .NET Core runtime are you? And which template version

Comment: @Tseng I use this version : 2.1.302

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a reference to [Microsoft.AspNetCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore/) and include the namespace `using Microsoft.AspNetCore;`. If you use a template, they usually include a meta-package. Depending on the version (2.0 or 2.1) and your IDE, it either will be [Microsoft.AspNetCore.All](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All) or [Microsoft.AspNetCore.App](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/2.1.3). There you will have all necessary packages included. Is convenient but you might want to add what you need manually.

The suggestion to [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/958d41f73858d0d2a388e82a36f7cc719dd0eb5f/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting/Internal/WebHost.cs#L27) is not what you are looking for. What you are looking for you find [here](https://github.com/aspnet/MetaPackages/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore/WebHost.cs#L22).