# WebHostBuilder does not contain definition for CreateDefaultBuilder

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

How do I utilize `CreateDefaultBuilder` when running `TestServer`?

```
TestServer _server = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder()
                .CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseContentRoot("C:\\TestAPI\\TestAPI.WebAPI")
                .UseEnvironment("Development")
```

Error:

> 'WebHostBuilder' does not contain a definition for
>   'CreateDefaultBuilder' and no accessible extension method
>   'CreateDefaultBuilder' accepting a first argument of type
>   'WebHostBuilder' could be found

This is for Webhost Builder not Webhost, so its not a duplicate question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['WebHost' does not contain a definition for 'CreateDefaultBuilder'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52072618/webhost-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-createdefaultbuilder)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating a new instance of `WebHostBuilder` and trying to call a method on that `WebHostBuilder`.  The `WebHostBuilder` class does not contain a method `CreateDefaultBuilder()`

`WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(...)` returns an instance of `IWebHostBuilder`.
You want to use `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(...)`

Comment: i do that and it says now, cannot create instance of static webhost